# better way to declare multiple depth routes in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two main routes I would like to make. One which is `assets/ANY_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS/browse` and `assets/ANY_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS`. The components that receive the ANY_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS ideally would just receive an array of the levels.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BrowseComponent },

  // all possible paths for browse //
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/:level3/:level4/browse', component: BrowseComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/:level3/browse', component: BrowseComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/browse', component: BrowseComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/browse', component: BrowseComponent },
  { path: 'assets/browse', component: BrowseComponent },

  // all possible paths for assets //
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/:level3/:level4/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/:level3/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:level2/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:level1/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: 'assets/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Which, while it certainly does work, isn't very elegant. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) for this.

Here's a way to implement it:

```js
const assetsUrlMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => {

  if (!segments.length || segments[0].path !== 'assets') {
    return null;
  }

  return { 
    consumed: segments,
    posParams: {
      id: segments[segments.length - 1],
      // Add other segments here..
    }
  };
};

const routes: Routes = [
  /* ... */
  {
    path: assetsUrlMatcher,
    component: AssetComponent,
  }
  /* ... */
];
```

```html
<button [routerLink]="['assets/level1/level2/level3/', 123]">Multiple levels</button>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-understanding-router?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).